# Maximum windowsize for an Azure alert

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create an alert for what seems a simple alert scenario:

> If my logic app is not started for a period of 24 hours I want to
> raise an alert for unexpected inactivity.

When I create the alert via the portal I can only select a timewindow of up to 6 hours.

[image]

But if I set it  up via the Portal API directly then I can configure a timewindow up to 1 day.

[image]

My question is why is the portal fixing the window size maximum to 6 hours for an alert? And am I going about this the right way - is there a better way to determine inactivity of certain logic apps? e.g. how could I alert if a logic app didn't trigger for 2 days?

Thanks.

Comment: Down vote? Vote to close? Care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertrules/createorupdate), Alert Rules can be created with a `windowsSize` between 5 minutes and 1 day in ISO 8601 duration format.

As you mentioned, this is supported via the API, and ARM Templates as well.

> why is the portal fixing the window size maximum to 6 hours for an
>   alert?

**I believe** this is just a UI limitation, but shouldn't be there.

> My other question is am I going about this the right way - is there a
>   better way to determine inactivity of certain logic apps? e.g. how
>   could I alert if a logic app didn't trigger for 2 days?

This is an OOTB functionality, I would recommend to use it as long as it meets your requirement. If you needed something else, like a longer period, you would need to implement something custom. You could use the [Workflow Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/WorkflowRuns/List) API and check it programmatically.

HTH